# How to add background image Animation in PyQt5 QPropertyAnimation in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I have done the following code for window animation but i am unable to display the background image in it

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5 import QtCore ,QtGui
from pyautogui import size

# GETTING SCREEN RESOLUTION

width , height = size()

class AppDemo(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # SETTING WINDOW GEOMETRY FOR ANIMATION 

        self.baseHeight = 0
        self.extendedHeight = height
        self.baseWidth = 0
        self.extendedWidth = width
        self.rect = QRect(0,0, self.baseWidth, self.baseHeight)
        self.setGeometry(self.rect)

        # CREATING FRAMELESS WINDOW

        flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.setStyleSheet("*\n"
"{\n"
"background-image:url(BACKGROUND.jpg);\n"
"}")
        self.resizeWindow()

    #THE ANIMATION EFFECT 

    def resizeWindow(self):
            
        currentHeight = self.height()
        currentWidth = self.width()

        if self.baseHeight == currentHeight and self.width() == currentWidth:
            baseHeight = self.baseHeight
            baseWidth = self.baseWidth
            extendedHeight = self.extendedHeight
            extendedWidth = self.extendedWidth
        else:
            baseHeight = self.extendedHeight
            baseWidth = self.extendedWidth
            extendedHeight = self.baseHeight
            extendedWidth = self.baseWidth    
        # STARTING ANIMATION

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'geometry')
        self.animation.setDuration(800)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QRect(0, 0, baseWidth, baseHeight))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QRect(0, 0, extendedWidth, extendedHeight))
        self.animation.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is the image shown without the animation?

Comment: Try adding `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)`